# L1 is not declared in this scope error

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a project where I have to control a DC motor. 
In this code the purpose is that every time you press a button the direction of the motor changes.

I only get the error that L1 (and L2,R1 and R2) are not declared in this scope. the place in the loop.
How do I define the variables so that the code works?

```
int Motorforward = 10;   // MotorDirectionPin set to pin10
int Motorbackward = 11;   // MotorDirectionPin set to pin11
const int button1Pin = 2; //button control set to pin 2

int state = L1;
int state = L2;
int state = R1;
int state = R2;

int button1State;  // current reading from the input pin
int previous = LOW; //the previous reading from the input pin

char input;

void setup(){
pinMode(button1Pin, INPUT); //set pin as input
Serial.begin(9600);


pinMode(Motorforward, OUTPUT); // sets the pin as output
pinMode(Motorbackward, OUTPUT);
 }



  void loop(){
button1State = digitalRead(button1Pin);
input = button1State;

switch(state){
  case L1:
    if (state == L1){
    if (button1State == HIGH){
        state == L2;
    }
  }
  break;

case L2:
  if (state == L2){
    if (button1State == LOW){
      state == R1;
    }
  }
  break;

case R1:
  if (state == R1){
    if (button1State == HIGH){
      state == R2;
    }
   }
  break;

case R2:
  if (state == R2){
    if (button1State == LOW){
      state == L1;
    }
  }
  break;
}
```

Comment: How many `state` variables do you want?!  And it is quite correct. At no point do you ever declare those symbols.

Comment: Do you mean the different states the motor can be in?
in that case 4 states in which case 1 and 2 and case 3 and 4 give the same result.

Comment: No, I mean how many `state` variables do you want? You define the same variable 4 times, each time with a different assignment, and an assignment to a variable or macro that you haven't defined at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the feeling you need only one state which can have 4 values: L1, L2, R1 or R2.

For this, use an enum:

```
enum EState { L1, L2, R1, R2 };
```

Now create one state variable of that type and give it an initial value.

```
EState state = L1;
```

Some other problems I see at first sight:

```
case L1:
  if (state == L1){
  if (button1State == HIGH){
      state == L2;
  }
}
break;
```

In this statement, when there is `case L1`, it means the code following ( until the break) is only handled when the state (because of `switch(state)` is L1, so you can remove the check `if (state == L1)`. What is left is:

```
case L1:
  if (button1State == HIGH)
  {
    state == L2;
  }
  break;
```

Than you use `state == L2` to set a new state. However, the `==` only compares two values, if you want to assign it, you have to use a single `=`, thus the code should be:

```
case L1:
  if (button1State == HIGH)
  {
    state = L2;
  }
  break;
```

Of course you have to do this also for the other case statements.

Tip: align your code (make the { and } aligned under each other; this will make your code readability much better.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined L1, L2, R1, or R2.  You're also redefining the int variable 'state' four times.

Try replacing:

```
int state = L1;
int state = L2;
int state = R1;
int state = R2;
```

With something like:

```
#define L1  1
#define L2  2
#define R1  3
#define R2  4
int state = R2;
```